# Safe to use Single KieSession instance in multithreading environment?

Tags: drools, kie

I and creating a rule engine with the help of drools. What I have done till now is that on server boot I have created singleton instance of `KieSession` using the `drl` file. I want to use this same instance for multiple rule evaluation in multithreaded  environment.

So what I am doing is that, after my fact is ready I will insert the fact in `kieSession`, Fire rules and post that I will delete the fact from the `kieSession`.

```
ExamplePojo examplePojo = new ExamplePojo();
FactHandle insertedFact = kieSession.insert(examplePojo);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.delete(insertedFact);
```

As per the `KieSession.delete` JavaDoc -

```
Retracts the fact for which the given FactHandle was assigned regardless if it has been explicitly or logically inserted.
```

Things I know -

- In multithreaded scenario `kieSession.fireAllRules()` can be called multiple times even when the fact from other thread is still in working memory
- I have tested that calling `kieSession.fireAllRules()` multiple times does not execute rules again on the already inserted facts if there are no explicit changes in rules in between the two fires
- `kieSession.delete(insertedFact)` is compulsory from memory leak point of view
- At any point of time there can be facts from multiple threads in the working memory at the same time

Questions I have -

- Will this scenario can cause malfunctioning in rule execution through some execution interference?
- Can this cause any sort if memory leaks the way I am using it?

Experts your advises are welcome. I am new to Drools and not aware of such use cases.

Comment: was there any further investigation from your side @saurav?

Comment: @VdeX kiesession object is not thread safe and you should not use singleton instance for sure in multithreading use case.. What I did is basically created a pool of kiesession pool and every new rule fire extract a kiesession from that pool.. once its done with the kiesession it puts it back to the pool after cleaning it... You can also destroy that kiesession instance and the pool will create a new one in place of this instance.. Pool saves creating kiesession on the go and saves time..

Comment: Thanks, I have created queue.